# Can dependency files of a library be copied programatically based on the library reference

Tags: c#

I have a library which does some printing logs to file functionality. 
This DLL is dependent on the .config file of the library project.

I had referenced this library from another project B. When I build the project B copy of the DLL reference is placed to output folder of project B. When I run the project B, DLL is taken from the output folder of Project B and when DLL tries to load the config file form same folder(Output folder Project B) it fails and doesn't work as expected.

Is there any way to copy the dependency config file when referenced as LIBRARY IN C#? 
Or is there any other way to handle the referencing of DLLs?

Comment: any reason you can't use post build events?